# Dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 w/Windows 11 (RST Disable)

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, acer, rst

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 (Dual boot) with Windows 11 (Already installed). Ubuntu says I need to disable RST. I have seen some problems related to this. Such as not booting Windows after installing Ubuntu.

Windows is installed on a NVME SSD  and I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my HDD

Laptop - Acer aspire 5 a515-55g

So how do I do this? I don't want to reinstall windows.

Comment: If you change to AHCI, you have to install AHCI drivers into Windows. But my Dell 11th gen Intel with only a NVMe drive, installed 22.04 using  the Intel® VMD driver. I actually forgot to change to AHCI first & it just worked (actually surprised.) I did have to turn off Windows fast start up & Windows bitlocker.